# Crud insert method

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

I am creating a database for employees, and I am applying the crud operation to it
The problem with the code is that I cannot insert data into the database from the fields, I also get this error:
do not access superglobal $_post array directly.

```
  <?php

  session_start();
  include("configa.php");


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $FirstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["FirstName"]);
  $LastName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["LastName"]);

// attempt insert query execution

 $sql = "INSERT INTO employeeinfo (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName')";

 if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)){

echo "Records added successfully.";}

 else{

  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

   }

// close connection




 $sql = 'INSERT INTO `employeeinfo`(`FirstName`, `LastName`) ';
  $sql = $sql . "VALUES   (\"$FirstName\", \"$LastName\") ";









if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";

    $_SESSION['completed'] = "YES";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }



header('Location: Employee.php');
}else
       {
    echo 'BYE BYE !!!';
      } 

  mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Is this inside a framework that's generating warnings about using `$_POST`? If so you should follow the recommended method for accessing parameters.

Comment: Additionally, `$mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE` is over-kill. Here `if ($mysqli->query($sql))` is more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

So the `filter_input()` method in php accepts a third parameter specifying what it should do as a filtering function. You could go with the filter `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`, judging by your case.

Refer the `filter_array` method in php manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Refer what filters are available in php : http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

What Filter am I using for this demo : http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

So your input assignment to variables will look like the following,

```
   $FirstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["FirstName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $LastName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["LastName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

And i gather you might be using NetBeans for PHP development (https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/improve_your_code_with_new). This has the same warning as you've mentioned. But I'm not quite sure you will see the warning around other IDE's.